# Где объявлять вспомогательные функции?

Tags: c++, ооп, code-style, css, оформление

К примеру, у меня есть класс, который делает WMI запросы, там часто надо преобразовывать `QString` к `BSTR`, поэтому я хочу написать функции преобразования.
Где мне их лучше объявлять, в этом же классе, если да, то `private` или `public`? Создать `namespace` с двумя функциями только для этого класса? Создать общий `namespace` для всех функций преобразования, и, пока что, записать туда только две эти функции? Объявить их глобально в хедере этого класса?

Comment: А объявления точно нужны? Может, просто поместить эти функции в файл cpp?

Comment: Вот это я вроде бы и хочу сделать

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Как пишет *Скотт Мейерс* в своей книге «*Эффективное использование C++*»:

> Предпочитайте функциям-членам функции, не являющиеся ни членами, ни друзьями класса. Это повышает степень инкапсуляции и расширяемость, а также гибкость упаковки функциональности.

Если хотите ознакомиться с этим правилом детальнее - см. стр. 105 вышеупомянутой книги.

Если Ваши функции выполняют преобразование и не требуют доступа к закрытам данным-членам или методам Вашего класса - пользуйтесь этим советом, поскольку, если свободная функция способна обеспечить ту же функциональность, что и метод класса, то предпочтительней является свободная функция, поскольку она увеличивает степень инкапсуляции данных. А это уже одна из особенностей, ожидаемых от ООП программ.

Идея использовать `namespace`, в который Вы поместите свой класс и эти функции преобразования, хорошая, явно лучше, чем подвесить их в глобальной области видимости.